# Powershell/SCCM - Get an SCCM deployment "Scheduled time" via powershell (or other)?

Tags: powershell, sccm

I have used PowerShell scripts which list deployments name and/or state for a given machine, however they do not list the deployment's "Scheduled Time" which I am after (see screenshot).

I basically want to program a script that asks for deployment name (e.g. `Notepad++ - Install`) and then it would return the scheduled time of this deployment. Is this at all possible?

[image: Scheduled Time Highlighted]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignments are available in the `AssignedSchedule`-property in the objects returned from `Get-CMPackageDeployment`.

AFAIK you can't set a deployment name in SCCM 2012+ like you could with advertisement name in 2007, so the sample below uses PackageName instead. You can change this to PackageID, CollectionID etc. Ex:

```
#Remember to import SCCM module and switch to sitename PSDrive, ex: Set-Location C00:
Get-CMPackageDeployment -Name ".NET Framework 4.6.2" | Select-Object PackageID, ProgramName, CollectionID, PresentTime, @{n="Assignments";e={$_.AssignedSchedule.StartTime}}

PackageID ProgramName            CollectionID PresentTime         Assignments                               
--------- -----------            ------------ -----------         -----------                                                   
C0000AF4  Install NET Framework  C000042D     16.03.2017 20:44:00 16.03.2017 20:44:00                       
C0000AF4  Install NET Framework  C0000BF2     03.05.2017 21:07:00 {03.05.2017 21:30:00, 03.05.2017 22:00:00}
```

`PresentTime` in the sample above is the "available date". Assignments above only show the start-time. If you have a reoccuring schedule you can get them from the same `AssignmentSchedule`-objects.